# change layout in jupyter + pycharm integration to show preview after the cells

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pycharm

is there a way to control the layout of jupyter notebook when using it inside pycharm?

currently, I have a side by side display:

[image]

is there a way to change it into layout similar to the web's version in jupyter itself? 
So that after every input cell, there would be the output of a cell...

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at the moment, unfortunately.

---

**Update 1:** PyCharm 2021.3+ has a new browser-like Jupyter layout by default (shared with DataSpell).

Comment: Is there at least a way to move the Preview panel to another location?

Comment: No, but try [DataSpell](https://www.jetbrains.com/dataspell/). It has a standard Jupyter-like layout. It will be merged back into PyCharm replacing the current Jupyter support once released.

Comment: That sounds great, I can't wait to start using it! Do you know how long it takes to receive the link after registering?